# scale keeps growing beyond math context precision

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am working on some code that calculates points on a 2 axis graph and I noticed that when the X or Y coordinate was value zero it slowed down.  I spit out some debug and found that the scale of my coordinate value was continually growing.  I thought passing the math context would make the return bigdecimal not be able to have a larger scale.  I was hoping to limit the scale to my math context precision.  This code shows what I am seeing.

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(32);
BigDecimal xPos = new BigDecimal("0.0", mc);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    System.out.println("" + xPos + " scale=" + xPos.scale());
    xPos = xPos.multiply(xPos, mc);
}
```

The scale continues to increase with each iteration.  Am I incorrect in thinking that because I pass multiply a math context that it should limit the precision of the return?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained in the [BigDecimal API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
Operation     Preferred Scale of Result

Add           max(addend.scale(), augend.scale())
Subtract      max(minuend.scale(), subtrahend.scale())
Multiply      multiplier.scale() + multiplicand.scale()
Divide        dividend.scale() - divisor.scale()
```

And it makes sense in a logarithmic sort of way.

Comment: My mistake was in thinking that passing a MathContext to multiply method would set the result to the scale of the MathContext.  But apparently it only looks at the RoundingMode.  Why it wants a MathContext when it really only wants a RoundingMode is beyond me.  After calling multiply I call setScale passing a scale and rounding mode and this allows me to limit the precision in my reiterative equation.